# Seleccion entre fechas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando realizar la selección de los eventos(`fullcalendar`) del día de hoy desde **PHP** y **MySQL**, para lo cual uso el siguiente código:

```
SELECT * FROM agenda.event 
WHERE event.start_event = CURRENT_DATE() 
AND event.end_event = CURRENT_DATE()
```

ahora dentro de mi tabla tengo datos como los siguientes:

```
______________________________________________________
id  title    start_event            end_event 
_______________________________________________________
1  evento1   2019-06-11 10:00:00    2019-06-11 12:00:00
2  evento2   2019-06-11 13:00:00    2019-06-11 15:00:00
3  evento3   2019-06-12 08:00:00    2019-06-12 10:00:00
4  evento4   2019-06-13 08:00:00    2019-06-13 10:00:00
```

> Para este caso solo debería obtener los del día de hoy es decir los 2 primeros `eventos(2019-06-11)`, pero no me retorna ningún evento.

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Otra posibilidad, siempre que tus columnas sean del tipo `datetime`,  es usar la cláusula `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
       FROM agenda.event 
       WHERE CURRENT_DATE() BETWEEN date(event.start_event) AND date(event.end_event)
```

- Convertimos los `datetime` a `date` para compararlos con `CURRENT_DATE()`

Comment: Me parece después de probar la consulta que no devuelve los valores esperados, pues así cómo está CURRENT DATE sólo devuelve el date y las columnas de la tabla del OP son datetime

Comment: Hola @Aprendiz,  es absolutamente cierto lo que dices, lo raro que lo había chequeado  antes en un fiddle. Hay que llevar las fechas a un date común

Comment: Si en una ocasión me pasó lo mismo con una respuesta, de hecho la edición a la mía se basó en la tuya e hice pruebas por qué tu respuesta es más lógica, salvo por el detalle en mención

Comment: @Aprendiz, viendo los puntos cosechados, evidentemente, aquí, se vota por reputación (lo cual no está bueno). Saludos.

Answer (score 6):

**Edición**

*Posible solución*

- El problema es que `CURRENT_DATE()` retorna un valor en `YYYY-MM-DD` por ejemplo: `2019-06-12` y tu estás usándolo para comparar con campos de tipo `DATETIME()` es decir que incluyen `hh:mm:ss` del tipo `2019-06-12 15:12:00.

Anexo:

- Usa `INTERVAL 1 DAY` para indicar que de la fecha que devuelve `CURRENT_DATE()` reste un día y así obtengas los valores buscados.
- La posible solución es que pases a las columnas de `start_event` y `start_end` por la función `DATE()` para solo obtener los valores *date* e ignorar la parte *TIME* del registro.

**CONSULTA**

```
SELECT * FROM agenda.event 
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
BETWEEN DATE(event.start_event)    
AND DATE(event.end_event);
```

- [Enlace a ejemplo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=68b9902b6ccc76909e3b37115a8637ab)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, con ese cambio me retorna los eventos del dia de mañana, sin embargo al hacer "SELECT CURRENT_DATE()" me retorna "2019-06-11" lo cual indica que la fecha del servidor esta bn, pero nose porque me trae los de mañana..

Comment: @DiegoAvila revisa la edición

Comment: no puede ser metí a la función `CURRENT_DATE()` en la función `DATE` cuando ya de por si la primera devuelve solo la parte *date* de la fecha...............